# Is it possible to modify drop plot code so that the output graph is displayed in iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

Is it possible to modify drop plot code so that the output graph is  displayed in iphone simulator.Now we are adding the CSV file externally. I want to Call the File through the code..

Comment: I am trying with the example of drop plot which is available in coreplot examples.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create an iOS application. The easiest way to demo this is to start with one of the iOS example apps. Copy the datasource code from Drop Plot into the new app, add the CSV parsing class, and add your CSV file to the app bundle. Read the CSV file into an NSString and parse it to populate the data for your plot datasource.